# When using a scrolled canvas in Tkinter, columns of contained frame are cut off

Tags: python, canvas, scroll, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter widget that contains a number of tables, which are currently frames with entries filled using the .grid method, which can be switched between by pressing buttons. My current attempt at a solution uses the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

def dot(root, num):
    root.subframe.destroy()
    root.subframe = TFrame(root, num)

root = Tk()

vscrollbar = Scrollbar(root,orient='vertical')
vscrollbar.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=N+E+W+S)

root.defaultframe = MainFrame(root)
root.canvas = Canvas(root, yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
root.subframe = Frame(root.canvas)
vscrollbar.config(command=root.canvas.yview)
root.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0)
root.subframe.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

where MainFrame has the following structure:

```
class MainFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.grid(row=0,column=0)
        b1 = Button(self, text='table 1', command=lambda: dot(root, 0))
        b2 = Button(self, text='table 2', command=lambda: dot(root, 1))
        b1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+W+S)
        b2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+E+W+S)
```

and TFrame:

```
class TFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, foor, num):
        Frame.__init__(self, root.canvas)
        for i in range(12):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, minsize=50)
        for x in range(12):
            for y in range(20):
                label = Label(self, text=num)
                label.grid(row=y,column=x,sticky=N+E+W+S)
        root.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self,anchor='nw')
        root.canvas.configure(scrollregion=root.canvas.bbox('all'))
```

When I run the code, pressing the buttons loads the tables, which scroll in the vertical as expected. But only the first 8 columns or so are visible, no matter how the window is resized. Changing the width of the MainFrame by adding empty labels and the like does not affect the size of the TFrame created, even if it is several times wider than the 8 columns the TFrame ends up being. While I could have a somewhat tolerable solution by adding a horizontal scroll bar as well as the vertical, my experiences so far with scrolling in tkinter in general have been negative enough that I hope to avoid using it by any possible means.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What's the question? How to add a horiontal scrollbar? How to ge the columns to grow? How to add more columns?

Comment: I suppose I could have been more clear. I want to know how to not have the columns after the first 8 cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found a solution. It turns out there weren't columns being cut off, the whole canvas was being cut off, and all my test cases just happened to have exactly the right number of columns vs column width that it looked like the columns after the first 8 were being cut off.

Changing:

```
root.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

to

```
root.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=N+E+W+S)
```

fixed the problem.